# BeautifulSoup does not returns all data

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse some data for the moon phase today using Python's library BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

moon_url = "http://www.moongiant.com/phase/today/"


try:
    rqest =  urllib2.urlopen(moon_url)
    moon_Soup = BeautifulSoup(rqest, 'lxml')
    moon_angle = 0
    moon_illumination = 0
    main_data = moon_Soup.find('div', {'id' : 'moonDetails'})
    print main_data

except urllib2.URLError:
    print "Error"
```

But the output instead of this:

```
<div id="moonDetails">        
      Phase: <span>Waxing Crescent</span><br>Illumination: <span>36%
</span><br>Moon Age: <span>6.00 days</span><br>Moon Angle: <span>0.55</span><br>Moon Distance: <span>364,</span>434.78 km<br>Sun Angle: <span>0.53</span><br>Sun Distance: <span>149,</span>571,918.47 km<br>
</div>
```

Is only this:

```
<div id="moonDetails">
</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: This data are in `var mArray` not in `<div id="moonDetails">`

Comment: Actually it's in var jArray. How can I parse jArray using Python?

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118337/fetch-data-of-variables-inside-script-tag-in-python-or-content-added-from-js

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually after the RaminNietzsche's comment I used ***dryscrape*** library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import dryscrape

    moon_url = "http://www.moongiant.com/phase/today/"

try:
    rqest =  urllib2.urlopen(moon_url)
    session = dryscrape.Session()
    session.visit(moon_url)
    response = session.body()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

    moon_data = soup.findAll('div', {'id':'moonDetails'})
    print moon_data
```

As a result the output now is:

```
<div id="moonDetails">        
      Phase: <span>Waxing Crescent</span><br>Illumination: <span>36%
</span><br>Moon Age: <span>6.00 days</span><br>Moon Angle: <span>0.55</span><br>Moon Distance: <span>364,</span>434.78 km<br>Sun Angle: <span>0.53</span><br>Sun Distance: <span>149,</span>571,918.47 km<br>
</div>
```

Thank's everyone for the answers!

Comment: doesn't seem to be windows compatible? There doc don't mention the install at all..

Answer (score 3):

As stated by RaminNietzsche in the comments, you should extract the text of your script in this particular `script` tag. You can use `regex` or `built-in methods` (like `split()`, `strip()` and `replace()`, for example.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

moon_url = "http://www.moongiant.com/phase/today/"
html_source =  requests.get(moon_url).text

moon_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

data = moon_soup.find_all('script', {'type' : 'text/javascript'})

for d in data:
    d = d.text
    if 'var jArray=' in d:
        jArray = re.search('\{(.*?)\}', d).group()
        moon_data = json.loads(jArray)
        print(moon_data)

        #if you want mArray data too, you just have to:
        # 1. add `'var mArray=' in d` in the if clause, and
        # 2. uncomment the following lines
        #mArray = re.search('\[+(.*?)\];', d).group()
        #print(mArray)
```

**Output:**

```
{'3': ['<b>April 4</b>', '58%\n', 'Sun Angle: 0.53291621763825', 'Sun Distance: 149657950.85286', 'Moon Distance: 369697.55153449', 'Moon Age: 8.1316595947356', 'Moon Angle: 0.53870564539409', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'April 4'], '2': ["<span style='color:#c7b699'><b>April 3</b></span>", 'Illumination: <span>47%\n</span>', 'Sun Angle: <span>0.53', 'Sun Distance: <span>149,</span>614,</span>943.28', 'Moon Distance: <span>366,</span>585.35', 'Moon Age: <span>7.08', 'Moon Angle: <span>0.54', 'First Quarter', '<b>Monday, April 3, 2017</b>', 'April', 'Phase: <span>First Quarter</span>', 'April 3'], '1': ['<b>April 2</b>', '36%\n', 'Sun Angle: 0.53322274612254', 'Sun Distance: 149571918.46739', 'Moon Distance: 364434.77975454', 'Moon Age: 6.002888839693', 'Moon Angle: 0.54648504798072', 'Waxing Crescent', 'April 2'], '4': ['<b>April 5</b>', '69%\n', 'Sun Angle: 0.53276322269153', 'Sun Distance: 149700928.5008', 'Moon Distance: 373577.14506795', 'Moon Age: 9.1657967733025', 'Moon Angle: 0.53311119464703', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'April 5'], '0': ['<b>April 1</b>', '25%\n', 'Sun Angle: 0.53337618944887', 'Sun Distance: 149528889.15122', 'Moon Distance: 363387.67496992', 'Moon Age: 4.9078487808877', 'Moon Angle: 0.54805974945761', 'Waxing Crescent', 'April 1']}
```

---

Since it's loaded as a `JSON`, you can navigate through it like this:

**Example Code:**

```
print(moon_data['4'])
print('-')*5
print(moon_data['4'][2])
```

**Output:**

```
['<b>April 5</b>', '69%\n', 'Sun Angle: 0.53276322269153', 'Sun Distance: 149700928.5008', 'Moon Distance: 373577.14506795', 'Moon Age: 9.1657967733025', 'Moon Angle: 0.53311119464703', 'Waxing Gibbous', 'April 5']
-----
Sun Angle: 0.53276322269153
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way whose essentials I've cribbed from root's answer at [access Chrome DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531790/access-chrome-dom-tree-with-python).

The idea is that you can use **selenium** and **lxml** together to gain access to the DOM of a page that has been loaded and processed by its javascript.

```
>>> moon_url = "http://www.moongiant.com/phase/today/"
>>> import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
>>> import lxml.html as html
>>> import lxml.html.clean as clean
>>> 
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> browser.get(moon_url)
>>> content = browser.page_source
>>> cleaner = clean.Cleaner()
>>> content = cleaner.clean_html(content)
>>> doc = html.fromstring(content)
>>> type(doc)
<class 'lxml.html.HtmlElement'>
>>> type(content)
<class 'str'>
>>> open('c:/scratch/content.htm','w').write(content)
27070
```

Once you have done that, as the final few statement above show, you can access the DOM either/both as HTML or as a tree suitable for processing with lxml. In your case, you might prefer to make soup with the HTML; that would mean applying BeautifulSoup to `content`.

Incidentally, when I saved `content` I did indeed find the following construct in the HTML, as one would expect.

```
<div id="moonDetails">
    Phase: <span>First Quarter</span><br>
    Illumination: <span>47%</span><br>
    Moon Age: <span>7.08 days</span><br>
    Moon Angle: <span>0.54</span><br>
    Moon Distance: <span>366,</span>585.35 km<br>
    Sun Angle: <span>0.53</span><br>
    Sun Distance: <span>149,</span>614,943.28 km<br>
</div>
```